# Accessing Eve db driver from custom authentication class

Tags: python, rest, api, authentication, eve

In my setting.py I declared custom authentication class

```
from flask import current_app as app

class MyAuth(BasicAuth):
    def check_auth(self, username, password, allowed_roles, resource, method):
        users = app.data.driver.db['users']

        ... some logic here...
```

And I use it in one of my domains:

```
my_clients = {
        'schema' :clientsSchema,
        'authentication': MyAuth
}
```

I get the following error:

```
File " ... eve/settings.py", line 24, in check_auth
users = app.data.driver.db['users']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Is there any way to access Eve db connection object from the MyAuth class and use it as in [the tutorial](http://python-eve.org/authentication.html) when the MyAuth class is declared in settings.py?

Comment: How are you running your app? I have a similar setup working.

Comment: I run it with `python run.py`

where run.py is

`app = Eve()

if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=80)
`

Answer (score 0):

On which Eve version are you? I think in older versions (prior to 0.6 the syntax for accessing the db driver was different.